# How to scroll Select objects in the hierarchy tab?

Tags: unity, selection

So I am creating breakable objects in unity and I have to select around 200 objects in the hierarchy tab so that I can apply some components to each the pieces. My problem is that once I select more than 100 objects in the hierarchy tab, it starts to bug out and it becomes incredible difficult to select objects. So I was wondering if there was a way to a scroll select or something like the box select like you can use on windows to easily select multiple items, or maybe some other way I didn't mention. It would really help me if someone could tell me a quick way to select multiple things in unity, in the hierarchy tab.

Thanks, Nova

Comment: Don't. There will almost definitely be a better way to do what you want to do if your current method is stressing the editor.

Comment: You may want to look at generating your gameobjects programatically instead of editing 200+ objects in a scene.